# Custom Package Repository Interface is not instantiable in Laravel 6

Tags: repository-pattern, laravel-6, service-provider, laravel-package

Target `[MyPackage\Crm\App\Repositories\CommentRepositoryInterface]` is not instantiable while building `[MyPackage\Crm\App\Http\CommentController]`.

The Controller in question `MyPackage\Crm\App\Http\CommentControllers.php` works fine if I inject the Repository as Object

```
public function __construct( \MyPackage\Crm\App\Repositories\CommentRepository\CommentRepository $commentRepository )
            {
                $this->noteRepo = $commentRepository; 
            }
```

but crashes if I try to inject the CommentRepositoryInterface.

```
public function __construct( \MyPackage\Crm\App\Repositories\CommentRepository\CommentRepositoryInterface $commentRepository )
            {
                $this->noteRepo = $commentRepository;
            }
```

My config/app.php

```
return [
MyPackage\Crm\App\CommentServiceProvider::class
]
```

Composer.json

```
    "MyPackage\\Crm\\":        "packages/mypackage/crm/src"
```

Interface

```
namespace MyPackage\Crm\App\Repositories;
{

interface CommentRepositoryInterface
{
    public function create( int $userId );
}
}
```

Repository class

```
namespace MyPackage\Crm\App\Repositories;


class CommentRepository implements CommentRepositoryInterface
{
    public function create(int $userId)
    {
        // TODO: Implement create() method.
    }
.....
}
```

My custom package provider class

```
namespace MyPackage\Crm\App;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use MyPackage\Crm\App\Repositories\CommentRepositoryInterface;
use MyPackage\Crm\App\Repositories\CommentRepository;

class CommentServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        include __DIR__.'/routes.php';

    }

    public function register()
    {

        $this->app->make('MyPackage\Crm\App\Http\CommentController');
        $this->app->bind(CommentRepositoryInterface::class, CommentRepository::class);
        
    }


}
```

`php artisan clear-compiled` doesn’t fix anything and throws the not instantiable error

Answer (score 0):

Taking out the

```
$this->app->make('MyPackage\Crm\App\Http\CommentController');
```

from the provider register method fix the issue.

Working provider code :

```
namespace MyPackage\Crm\App;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use MyPackage\Crm\App\Repositories\CommentRepositoryInterface;
use MyPackage\Crm\App\Repositories\CommentRepository;

class CommentServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        include __DIR__.'/routes.php';

    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(CommentRepositoryInterface::class, CommentRepository::class);
        
    }


}
```